# WARNING: ABIs [armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by 'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'ARMEABI' not targeted by this project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I had this issue last time after upgrade NDK version to latest version in Android Studio. I also found solution to fix this. If anyone has this issue , I hope it is the best question and answer for you. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found solution by reading on [release note here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-android-native-development.html) for NDK revision 16.

1. If you config your project with *`Application.mk`* just add the following to your *`Application.mk`* file:

   ```
   APP_STL := c++_shared
   ```
2. If you're using *`CMake`* via Gradle, add the following to your build.gradle:

   ```
   externalNativeBuild {
       cmake {
           cppFlags ""
           arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
       }
   }
   ```

To keep up to date with new release and note, please follow this [NDK Revision History](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history) to apply with new changed.

I hope it can fix your issue.

Comment: I have added the c++_shared to get the compilation to work at all with NDK-r18, however, I still have the same ARMEABI warning. Not sure what is trying to use this now.

Comment: @chivorn I think NDK-r16 still supported this so it wouldn't be a problem there. It still happens for me with NDK-r18

Comment: @JimLeask I also use ndk-r18. Same warning from Java compiler when it is building for devices.

Comment: The warning is gone, but the app crashes upon start. (gradle build, NDK 19)

Comment: Checked for NDK 20. The warning still exists.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#mips_mips64_and_armeabi) this is a known issue, and its due to the fact that the gradle plugin still includes unsupported ABIs by default. armbeabi was deprecated in NDKr16 and removed in r17 hence the warning. To fix, list your supported architectures under `splits.abi`:

```
...
splits {
    abi {
        ...
        reset()
        include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", ...
    }
}
```

Comment: my build already included `reset()` but still showing warning

Comment: Is the warning mentioning `"armeabi"`? After using `reset()` you may still see warnings about other architectures depending on your build file.

Comment: Yes, getting the exact same warning as OP

Comment: My last guess it would be some Android Studio caching then

Answer (score 2):

Got same issue and fixed through modifying the module build.gradle file by adding below setup:

```
android {
    ...
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a' //select ABIs to build APKs for
            universalApk true //generate an additional APK that contains all the ABIs
        }
    }

    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                   project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

For your reference, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't resolve my problem, i resolved by adding this:

```
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
```

to android.defaultConfig