# Android first time setup warning turns into errors

Tags: java, android

So i wanted to dive into some android development but i seem to be running into a problem that google doesn't seem to have answers too.

First up here is the Hello World tutorial i'm following. (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/)

So i managed to send the default package to my phone with the Hello World MainActivity but once i try to add some UI elements (and contain them) I get 1 error and 1 warning when i try to compile it.
`WARNING: ABIs [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi]` set by `android.injected.build.abi` gradle flag contained 'ARMEABI' not targeted by this project.

After messing around with the packages, uninstalling all my other coding software and restarting my PC a few times i noticed when i would start a new project i would have a warning straight away, With my MainActivity.java

L20 `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);`

> Warning: Cannot resolve symbol 'sample_text' / Casting
>   'findViewById(R.id.sample_text)' to 'TextView' is redundant.

I've tried reinstalling the SDK and installing all the packages but i'm not to sure and am almost ready to give up sadly so any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Have you passed this tutorial, or you still need help with it?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have found two helpful links to your answer for The first question i.e

> WARNING: ABIs [arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by
>   'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'ARMEABI' not
>   targeted by this project.
>   here is most helpful link
>   [WARNING: ABIs [armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by 'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'ARMEABI' not targeted by this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286817/warning-abis-armeabi-v7a-armeabi-set-by-android-injected-build-abi-gradle-f)

for the second one TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text); Warning: Cannot resolve symbol 'sample_text' / Casting 'findViewById(R.id.sample_text)' to 'TextView' is redundant.

one is warning of casting TextView i.e (TextView) this doesn't have any problem on compilation and its not finding text view by id of sample_text so check id of your textview field from xml file. If its there the problem is its not compiling and it will be solved when you take over the warning.

Comment: I can't seem to find application.mk, Im new to the Android SDK.

Comment: Removing C++ from the new project window seems to fix it, but then doesn't that mean i cant use C++ :( lol shouldn't all this just work? i blame windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

enter code like this the warning will disappear`enter code here`

TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);