# Unsupported ABI for NDK r19+: ARMEABI

Tags: flutter, gridle

Hey everyone i open my pervious project  when i run show me gridle error  help me to solve that error thanks

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':rive_common.

> Unsupported ABI for NDK r19+: ARMEABI[error of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFpQP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in `build.gradle`

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
       ndk {
           abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
       } 
   }
}
```

If still doesn't work, update or reinstall the ndk

This might be helpful [WARNING: ABIs [armeabi-v7a,armeabi] set by 'android.injected.build.abi' gradle flag contained 'ARMEABI' not targeted by this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286817/warning-abis-armeabi-v7a-armeabi-set-by-android-injected-build-abi-gradle-f)